# Getting absolutely no response from Web API when using HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, httpresponsemessage

I'm using *HttpResponseMessage* on my Web API because it simplifies things greatly. The issue I'm having is that, when testing the code in VS 2017 running under IIS Express, my code executes without issues, but I get absolutely nothing in response when I test from Postman. I'm wondering if it's related to headers and/or config. This is what Postman sends back:

**Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:12345/Url/RequestUrl.**

This is the part of the code that's running:

```
[OperationContract]
[ADAuthorize(Action = "RequestUrl", Controller = "Url")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage RequestUrl(Stream inputServiceRequestParameters)
{
    Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

    try
    {
        // Retrieve and place JSON parameters into object.
        var serviceRequestParameters = JsonFunctions.GetServiceRequestParameters(inputServiceRequestParameters);
        // Retrieve member GUID from LDAP.
        var contactId = LdapFunctions.GetMemberCrmGuid(serviceRequestParameters.MemberNumber);

        // Member information not found in LDAP, so return without processing.
        if (contactId == null)
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                JsonFunctions.BuildErrorResponse("", Constants.ValidationMessage.MEMBER_NOT_IN_LDAP));

            response.Content = new StringContent(JsonFunctions.BuildErrorResponse("", Constants.ValidationMessage.MEMBER_NOT_IN_LDAP));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            return response;
        }
```

[rest of the class continues after this...]

All this code runs beautifully but *nothing is returned*. Even Fiddler complains that *ReadResponse() failed*.

I've looked at an insane amounts of examples and I still can't figure out what is going on, what I'm missing.

Comment: Are you sure that RequestUrl method is called after request done. Problem may be in binding request to method.

Comment: The method is being called, definitely, as I can trace it through debug, line by line. However, something that bothers me is that I need to create a new instance of the Request object, because otherwise it's null, so it gives me the impression that the Request is not the actual api request being processed, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
contactId
```

may be null. If so, your code probably returns a null response, which would cause the behavior you describe.

Comment: The response is definitely not null. The var contactId is definitely null, which is the reason why I want to return the error. I've looked at it just before returning it, and it has the contents and the correct http status code... everything.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: basically I had a mix-up of MVC and Web API references, with some WFC in the config! I know, that happens when you reference old experimental code. Lesson learned for sure. The thing is that .Net won't scream any errors, it will just silently fail.